# Trying to Create an Excel Doc with PHP (Fatal Error)

Tags: php, excel

Hi guys i'm trying to create a simple Excel document so that I can start to understand how to use php with Excel. However, when I run my code i'm getting a fatal error... `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel::getActiviteSheet() in /home3/hutch/public_html/Murphy/ExcelTransfer.php on line 6`
Anyone know how to fix this?

```
<?php
    Include_once 'PHPExcel.php';

    $sheet = new PHPExcel();

    $activeSheet = $sheet->getActiviteSheet();

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A1','test1');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B1','test2');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('C1','test3');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('D1','test4');

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="report.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_I0Factory::createWriter($sheet, 'Excel2007');
    $obWriter->save('php://output');

    exit;

?>
```

Comment: Is there a typo on the method name? I'd expect it to (following the spelling of the word activity)  be $sheet->getActivitySheet();

Comment: I suggest you use a proper IDE (PHPStorm, Netbeans, etc) which will give you code completion. It would have made it easier to figure out the correct method as mentioned by Tomasz in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo use `$sheet->getActiveSheet();` instead of `$sheet->getActiviteSheet();`

Comment: This as fixed my issue thank you, I've had to change the file extension from xlsx as Excel wouldn't open so I tried a xls and it will open but I get a warning message saying `The file format and extension don't match. The file could be corrupt or unsafe. Unless you trust its sources, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?` How can I fix this

Comment: Also its out putting this: `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'PHPExcel_I0Factory' not found in <b>/home3/hutch/public_html/Murphy/ExcelTransfer.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />`

Comment: @MattHutch - `PHPExcel_I0Factory` !== `PHPExcel_IOFactory`.... it's a capital letter `I` and a capital letter `O` (as in the standard abbreviation for Input/Output), not a number zero (`0`)

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for spotting that, I'm still getting the same issue any ideas why this is?

Comment: Got it, was the `$obWriter` missed the j should have been `$objWriter`